# Перерисовка View при изменении одного из свойства поля LiveData | Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, activity-life-cycle, livedata

Пытаюсь разобраться с LiveData.

Создал экземпляр:

```
var data: MutableLiveData<Book> = MutableLiveData<Book>()
```

Getter&Setter:

```
fun setData(context: Context, id: String, res: Book.Resource) {
    data.value = //получаю экземпляр объекта Book
}

fun getLiveData() = data
```

Во фрагменте я добавляю слушателя:

```
model.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        title.text = it.title
        description.text = it.description
        //и т.д.
    })

    model.setData(root.context, id, resource!!)
```

И тут возникает вопрос, как **подписаться** на **внутренние** компоненты **Book**? Вот пример:

> У класса Book есть следующие свойства: id, title, image, genre и т.д;
> я через ссылку model.data(т.е. на прямую через переменную) изменяю,
> допустим, **свойство title**. Мне надо, чтобы и на **view** все тоже
> обновилось. У RecyclerAdapter есть **notifyDataSetChanged**, а есть ли
> такое **у LiveData**?

Или придется делать как-то так (**костылями**)?

```
val m = model.data.value
m?.title = "adad"
model.data.value = m
```

Answer (score 0):

`LiveData` ориентируется на работу с immutable объектами. Т.е. если ваш объект поменялся, то вы должны предоставить (создать) полностью новый объект, в вашем случае просто еще раз вызвать `setData(...)`, возможно предварительно проверив были ли реальные изменения.

Если говорить о `RecyclerView`, то там та же история.
Используя `DiffUtil` вы получите измененный объект, сравните его со старым, сформируете payload с изменениями, он придет в `public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads)` в адаптер, и вы сможете применить необходимые изменения, притом только те, которые реально поменялись. И  `notifyDataSetChanged` использовать не стоит, даже если очень хочется.